# Gauss Jacobi and Gauss Seidel in not diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What would be the appropriate answer if the matrix is not diagonally dominant and you are opt to use Gauss Jacobi and Gauss Seidel?

Is it the matrix's solution does not converge? or there is other way

Comment: Sorry what is the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What if the matrix is not diagonally dominant? and cannot be turned into one? Are Gauss Jacobi and Seidel cannot be performed?

Comment: I am thinking of putting "the solution will not converge" as my answer on my homework but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Should I do like 5 interations and tell that it will not converge? I'm sorry I'm overthinking things

Comment: Gauss-Seidel also converges for every symmetric positive definite matrix.